# Sick Tillandsia Caput Medusae

Tags: diagnosis, tillandsia

My airplant has developed a couple of brown spots on a couple of its limbs.  I just recently bought it from a local Lowes.  I brought home 2 of them and one looks completely healthy to me while the other has developed this symptom.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hello Jessica, For more accurate answers, you should post a picture of the affected plant.

Comment: We have to have pictures and a lot more information about your plant.  How long ago did you purchase, did you transplant, what have you fertilized with, are you using potting soil how do you decide when to water.  Where do these airplants live in your home?